# How to prevent users from posting their password?

Tags: php, security

Does anyone have any ideas on how you could prevent a user from posting their password on a site using php?

Comment: @mcbeab: you are coding a website for a bank ;-)

Comment: Provide a filter that turns their password into a certain word.  For instance, SO uses drool.  My password is: drool.  See?  Try it yourself!  (just kidding)

Comment: since you should be hashing and salting passwords, you will have no way of knowing what a user's password is. So in theory at least, there's not really any way of telling if a user is posting plain text or their password, and if you were to go through all text they post and test all the combinations of substrings of their input to see if that matched the hash, which would be prohibitively intensive, then you'd have a security problem. @BeemerGuy is right; there's no easy way to make sure users aren't submitting their passwords in other input fields.

Comment: Even if the technical implementation is completely unreasonable, you should ask yourself why such measures are important.

Comment: personal note: next time choose a password like "microsoft" or "firefox" ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could entirely forbid (for passwords) using dictionary words, names, dates or anything other sequence of characters that people might use in a conversation. Then, for every message, loop over every word in the message, hash it, then compared it to your store of hashed passwords.

This would be require a lot of CPU, and be easy to bypass though.

If people want to be idiots and tell other people their account details, you can't stop them.

To save them from phishing, you can only educate them.

To save yourself from multiple people sharing a single account, you can only look for patterns which suggest the account is being shared (such as being logged in from many different IP addresses at once — but be careful as people may access a service from a computer and phone at the same time, or use an ISP that slaps a rotating proxy in front of its users).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the password in session or where ever you want and try to match the password when the user post a comment but I wouldn't do that because:

- you will end up storing the clear password somewhere which is **really** bad
- you will clutter your code with hundred of useless checks

I think in this case the prevention is the way to go, just make a nice blurb on your registration and login pages that user shouldn't give their password, post it on site.

The other way to go is like BeemerGuy mentionned jsut hire some humans to moderates the comments on your website.

Comment: and @Ragez -- one of you misspelled the other's name!

Comment: @BeemerGuy: fixed with my deepest apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever see it happen? Probably not!

Why:

- Or you need to save the password as plain-text (lucky hackers!).
- Or you need to hash each word to compare it to the hashed password, very expensive.

So you just can't do it properly!
Don't even try it, explain the users why it is bad and just hope they don't post it ...